# Function onedit on sharing sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

i've try to call function when somebody edit range a1, it work, but when i share sheet to anyone can edit, it dont work, how i can modify when i sharing sheet to anyone can edit, function onEdit will work

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  var range = e.range;
  var spreadSheet = e.source;
  var sheetName = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var column = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var inputValue = e.value;
  
  if(sheetName == 'Xsender' && column == 1 && row == 1)
  {  
    let ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  let correctAnswer ="123"
  //ui.prompt("How are u today")
  let attempt=""
  while (attempt != correctAnswer) {
    attempt = ui.prompt("enter pass").getResponseText()
  }
ui.alert("ok")
}

}
```

Comment: The `onEdit(e)` function is a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) that runs automatically when the spreadsheet is _manually edited_. It should run fine with "anyone with link who can **edit**." It will _not_ run with "anyone with link who can **view**." You can open [My Executions](https://script.google.com/home/executions) to confirm that the function runs every time the spreadsheet is manually edited.

Comment: I edited my sheet on firefox and share to anyone can edit. On chrome, open the sheet and nothing happen https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yttlpymK-_ZHLwpro99QDzfRSDSGqQeWJwBOx3t5srY/edit#gid=0

Comment: You are apparently trying to add "password protection" to the spreadsheet. There is no reliable way to do that through a script. Use **File > Share** features instead. See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)

Comment: function onOpen(){
  //protectByPassword()
   let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  const adminEmail ="xxx@gmail.com"
  let correctAnswer ="1"
   let attempt=""
   let userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()
   if (adminEmail != userEmail){
    while (attempt !=correctAnswer){
     attempt = ui.prompt("Pass").getResponseText()
    }
  ui.alert("OK")}
}       Can i run function onOpen() if the user DONT sign in to their Google Account.

Comment: Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Again, you cannot reliably protect a spreadsheet with a script. The easiest way to bypass the "protection" is to wait until the script times out, which happens after 30 seconds with a simple trigger.

Answer (score 0):

> open the sheet and nothing happen

The question specifies the `onEdit(e)` function. That function does not run when the spreadsheet is **opened**. It runs when the spreadsheet is ***manually* edited**.

The `onEdit(e)` function is a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers). It runs for anyone who can edit the spreadsheet, including users whose access is through "anyone with link is editor", provided that the user is *signed in to their Google Account*.

Use the [My Executions](https://script.google.com/home/executions) dashboard to review when each function runs.